# Node/ Express Rest API keeps entering same controller function inspite of correct mapping

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, mean-stack

I am writing a node/express rest api.

Hitting,
http://localhost:5000/api/news

and

http://localhost:5000/api/news/?id=c5f69d56be40e3b56e55d80

both give me all the news objects because it enters the same .getNews function on for both the urls.

**My controller:**

```
const NewsController = {};
const News = require('../models/news.model');

// This implementation of getNews is using Promises
NewsController.getNews = function(req, res) {

  console.log('Inside getNews');
  sendResponse = function(arg) {
    res.json(arg);
  }

  const allnews = News.find({}, function(err, ns) {
    sendResponse(ns);
  });


};


// ES6 style
NewsController.getSingleNews = async (req, res) => {

  console.log("Inside getSingleNews");
  const news = await News.findById(req.params.id);
  res.json[news];
};


NewsController.createNews = async (req, res) => {
  const news = new News(req.body);
  await news.save();

  res.json[{
    'status': 'item saved successfully'
  }];
};

NewsController.deleteNews = async (req, res) => {
  await News.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id);
  res.json[{
    'status': 'item deleted successfully'
  }]
};


module.exports = NewsController;
```

**My routes.js**  (I am using the router at /api.  So app.js has // use Router

> app.use('/api', newsRoutes);

)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
var newsController = require('../controllers/NewsController')

router.get('/news', newsController.getNews);
router.get('/news/:id', newsController.getSingleNews);
router.post('/news', newsController.createNews);
router.delete('news/:id', newsController.deleteNews);

module.exports = router;
```

**My Model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const { Schema } = mongoose;
const newsSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  content: { type: String, required: true },
  author: { type: String },
  image: { type: String },
  source: { type: String }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('news', newsSchema);
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but what about changing the order of the two GET routes? It might help

Comment: @devnull69 Just tried that. doesn't work. Still hits only the getNews function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use /news/:id first. Your request will be redirected to the first matched url following the declaration order.

So /api/news satisfies app.get(/news)? Yep, gets redirected to that controller.
/api/news/?id=c5f69d56be40e3b56e55d80 satisfies app.get(/news)? Yep, also gets redirected to /news controller.

By the way, as your getting the id from req.params you should use /news/c5f69d56be40e3b56e55d80. If you were to get it from req.query you wouldn't need another route. /news?id=c5f69d56be40e3b56e55d80 would be perfect, you'd just need to check the existence of req.query.

Comment: Thanks!. Everything works now except ( POST i.e createNews).  It gives me a 

(node:7460) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: news validation failed: content: Path `content` is required., title: Path `title` is required.

I am trying to POST the below json where I provide all the values.

{
        "title": "Coffee",
        "content": "Coffee may be good for your health",
        "author": "Victor",
        "image": "iuyf056",
        "source": "ABC"
}

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is the way you are trying to call your endpoint. **Express routes don't match query string parameters**.

Having said that, your call to the *news* endpoint that looks like this:

http://localhost:5000/api/news/?id=c5f69d56be40e3b56e55d80

Should look like this instead:

http://localhost:5000/api/news/c5f69d56be40e3b56e55d80

That way the *id* parameter will get mapped to the *req.params.id* property inside your *getSingleNews* controller.

Being that the expected behavior for the way you declared your route:

```
router.get('/news/:id', newsController.getSingleNews);
```

For more information on how express routes work, check the documentation here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: Thanks!. Everything works now except ( POST i.e createNews).  It gives me a 

(node:7460) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: news validation failed: content: Path `content` is required., title: Path `title` is required.

I am trying to POST the below json where I provide all the values.

{
        "title": "Coffee",
        "content": "Coffee may be good for your health",
        "author": "Victor",
        "image": "iuyf056",
        "source": "ABC"
}

Comment: That's because your call to save news:
**await news.save();**
 is failing, wrap it around a **try/catch** and see what the error description says.

Comment: Its a validation error. But I don't understand why. I provide title and content in my json. Here is the O/P:


{ ValidationError: news validation failed: content: Path `content` is required., title: Path `title` is required.

  errors:
   { content: SAME ERROR AS FOR TITLE
 
     title:
      { 
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        properties: [Object],
        kind: 'required',
        path: 'title',
        value: undefined,
        reason: undefined,
        [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true } },
  _message: 'news validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError' }

Comment: you need to validate the structure of the body received by the controller